# What is this C# code doing?

Tags: c#, encryption

Can you help me to understand this C# code? I'm haven't any experience in the C# programming (but I have knowledge in the Delphi, Pascal, C/C++ and little bit in JS)

As I can see this code is trying to encrypt some **in.jpg** file and save encrypted data in the **out.jpg**. But I can't to understand this encrypt algorithm.

Sorry for my English.

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Encrypt(FileStream inFile, FileStream outFile)
    {
      BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader((Stream) inFile);
      Dictionary<byte, byte> dictionary = new Dictionary<byte, byte>(256);
      BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter((Stream) outFile);
      byte num1 = (byte) 0;
      do
      {
        try
        {
          byte key = binaryReader.ReadByte();
          if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            dictionary.Add(key, num1++);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (EndOfStreamException ex)
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      while ((int) num1 <= (int) byte.MaxValue);
      binaryReader.BaseStream.Position = 0L;
      for (int index = 0; index < 256; ++index)
        dictionary[(byte) index] = (byte) ((uint) (ushort) index ^ (uint) dictionary[(byte) index]);
      byte num2 = (byte) 0;
      while (true)
      {
        try
        {
          byte index = binaryReader.ReadByte();
          byte num3 = (byte) ((uint) dictionary[index] + (uint) num2);
          num2 = num3;
          binaryWriter.Write(num3);
          binaryWriter.Write((byte) ((uint) dictionary[index] ^ (uint) index));
        }
        catch (EndOfStreamException ex)
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      binaryReader.Close();
      binaryWriter.Close();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      FileStream inFile = new FileStream("in.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      FileStream outFile = new FileStream("out.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
      Program.Encrypt(inFile, outFile);
      inFile.Close();
      outFile.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _[Perhaps a good book on c#?](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Beginners-Introduction-Step---Step/dp/1507707614/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1426146370&sr=1-1&keywords=c%23+for+beginners)_.  I notice you used the "JetBrains decompiler" - hope it wasn't commercial software prior to posting here?

Comment: XOR is not encryption... Also the code is horrible and inefficient. I would not bother.

Comment: @MickyDuncan: If this is commercial, they wasted money on useless code ;p

Comment: @leppie lol yes it's not terribly good

Comment: @MickyDuncan: You could probably do this in one line of perl/sed/maybe even C#.

Comment: @leppie to be fair they probably had an intern do it ;)

Comment: @GrawCube: The 5 minutes it took me at consulting rates would still be cheaper than the 40 hours the intern spent on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same thing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int b, i = 0;
  var input = Console.OpenStandardInput();
  var output = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
  while ((b = input.ReadByte()) != -1)
  {
    output.WriteByte((byte)(b ^ i));
    i++;
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Program.exe < inputfile > outputfile
```

Run once to 'encrypt', run again on output file to 'decrypt'.

**Note:** This is **NOT** encryption.

You can compare the contents with `diff`, `comp` or your favourite diff tool.

Comment: Nice.  Isn't the original code doing 2 writes for every 1 read though?

Comment: @MickyDuncan: I think so, but did not bother with that obscurity :)

Comment: No worries.  :)   Your profile made me laugh.